# FFMPEG Drawtext Time

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to set when the drawtext of this FFmpeg command starts, I've tried with start_number but looks like it will not do the trick.

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -acodec aac -keyint_min 20 -r 20 -vcodec libx264 -crf 22 -b 1000k -bt 1000k -y -v 0 -bf 16 -threads 0 -vf drawtext="start_number=20:fontfile=/home/admin/script/impact.ttf:text='My Text':fontsize=15:fontcolor=white:x=w-30*t:y=10" output.mp4
```

I've tried different approaches, but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`start_number` is a parameter for used for an input image sequence/pattern.

If you want to draw a text on a video starting from the 3rd second you could use:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -vf drawtext="text='My Text':enable=gt(t\,3)" output.mp4
```

Please notice that encoding parameters were omitted and you should add them to meet your requirements.

Comment: The issue with it is it will keep starting at 0 seconds but will be enabled at 3 seconds, what I need is the scroll to start at X seconds.

Comment: if you want to scroll (skip) the video to X second from the start, use `-ss 00:00:03 -i 1.mp4`

Comment: @Zae if you want the scroll to start with X second treated as it was started from 0 you could combine: `enable=gt(t\,X)` and `x=w-30*(t-X)`